# Don't use default focus animation for UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, focus, tvos

I have a very simple cell and I want the text to be `1.0` alpha when focused and `0.5` when unfocused. This works by overriding `didUpdateFocusInContext`

```
import Foundation

class SettingsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

    var textColor:UIColor?

    if self.focused == true {
        textColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0)
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    }

    let attributedTitle = self.textLabel?.attributedText?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
    let range =  NSMakeRange(0, attributedTitle.length)
    attributedTitle.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: textColor!, range: range)
    self.textLabel?.attributedText = attributedTitle

}
```

}

HOWEVER, I don't want the white background when focused... how to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your cells' `focusStyle` to `UITableViewCellFocusStyleCustom` and UIKit won't do any default focus appearance at all on the cells: it'll be entirely up to you.